# Defining the key of a plist using another defined variable in common lisp

Tags: lisp, key, plist, common-lisp

Inside common lisp, I have a variable 'name' defined as:

```
(setq name ':length-1)
 >> :length-1
```

Now I want to make a plist using this variable and I want it to look like:

```
(:length-1 10)
```

Is there a way to define the key of the plist using another defined variable?

I have tried 'format' but that gives me a string and not the symbol:

```
(list (format nil ":~a" name) 10)
```

but this gives me:

```
(":lifting-surface" 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(list name 10)
```

But if you're getting `":lifting-surface"` rather than `":length-1"` when you use `format`, you must have changed the value of `name`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to make a keyword symbol from a string, I would suggest the make-keyword function from the alexandria library which looks like this:

```
(defun make-keyword (name)
  "Interns the string designated by NAME in the KEYWORD package."
  (intern (string name) :keyword))
```

EDIT: Oh, I see that you are not, but this might be useful anyways.